# Error trying to load XML file in Spark 2.0.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to load an xml file in spark version 2.0.0, as a newbie. This is what I did so far.

started my spark shell with the following:

`spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1`

I got series of errors and my spark shell did not start

ERROR:

> UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCES

```
com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1: not found
```

Comment: Check your Scala version, above dependency works with Scala 2.10. I have checked the dependency, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @DuyNguyenHoang scala version is 2.10.1